# getEmbeddedPicture: Call to getEmbeddedPicture failed when i put more than one mp3-file

Tags: java, android, android-file

i have a problem: i implemented an android project which plays a song when i push a button. also it shows in an another view (the app has two fragments) the meta-data of the mp3-file. i mean with meta-data the name of the interpreter, songcover ... i have only one mp3-file in the raw-directory. but when i put an another mp3-file in the raw-directory (only  this without changing the code) , the meta-information disappears suddenly. the results are null. these are not longer displayed. when i delete the one mp3-file it displayed again the meta-data. can s.o. tell me why i could not put another mp3-file in the raw-directory? i dont understand it. :(
i changed nothing in the code, only put an another mp3-file. then it does not work.

how can i fix it? thanks in advance

Comment: no one can help me with this?? :(

Answer (score 0):

Try something like loading each inside an AsyncTask:

```
private class LoadImageTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap>{

    private ImageView artImage;

    public LoadImageTask(ImageView image){
        artImage = image;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        retriever = new MediaMetadataRetriever();
    }

    @Override
    protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... params) {
        retriever.setDataSource(params[0]);
        byte[] art = retriever.getEmbeddedPicture();
        Bitmap bitmap = null;
        if( art != null ){
            bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(art, 0, art.length);
        }
        return bitmap;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap bm) {
        if( bm != null ){
            artImage.setImageBitmap(bm);
        }
        else{
            artImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.no_image);
        }
    }

}
```